# Hosting CodeIgniter project on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, dns, hosting

i have a website developed in php CodeIgniter framework which is presently working on my localhost.
the present working url on my localhost is

`http://localhost/myproj/index.php/xyz`

`xyz` is my first controller from which the home page is called.

i want to host on a particular domain as `http://www.example.com` and it works same as the above url `(http://localhost/myproj/index.php/xyz)`

Comment: You want to show "localhost" instead of your domain?

Comment: no no i want only `mydomain.com ` to be displayed when my home page is loaded

Comment: It will automatically then...Did you try?

Comment: i havent tried. but logically i was thinking the domain name would be the base url set. but my base url is `http://localhost/myproj/`

Comment: 1) Try; 2) If you wrote the base_url in config file, change it; if you didn't, it will be guessed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prathik change your base_url with your domain and mention your default_controller in config/routes.php file.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function named index in welcome.php, and then when you try to access http://domain.com index function will start.